# Vaio SB - Turn off AMD Graphics Card?

Tags: ati, vaio, overheating, fan, hybrid-graphics

I've got a Vaio SB with Hybrid Graphics (Intel Graphics Card and AMD/ATI Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series). It is running in Dual-Boot with Windows 7 and has the latest BIOS-Update. For reason that the laptop overheats (btw. 25-30W measured with Powertop)and the fan is permanently running, I tried to deactivate the AMD, without success. I did:

- the vgaswitcheroo, which is usually recommended, but it definitely doesn't work for me. I tried it in every variation I could encounter online (aprox. 10, especially other Vaio S users, but they have mostly NVIDIA which can get turned off with other methods that don't apply to me). At least the terminal tells me now that it is powered off, but I don't perceive any difference in temperature or energy consumption

  > 0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
  >   1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
- Tried to get the catalyst running. Does not work.
- laptop-mode-tools and other tools help a bit, but don't make the big difference, as long as the AMD is running

...same configuration, same problems, anyone? thx

ps. I am a Linux Beginner so I can't do everything and often don't understand the processes behind, but even if it would possible to physically remove the AMD I would do that. Although I am not sure if Laptop would still boot afterwards.